# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.' al querer hacer un buscador

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, oledb

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    cadena.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\db\Pruebas.accdb"
    cadena.Open()
    Dim Abarrotes As String
    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ods As DataSet
    Dim registro As Byte
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        Abarrotes = "Select*From Abarrotes Where ID=' " & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(Abarrotes, cadena)
        ods = New DataSet
        oda.Fill(ods, "Abarrotes")
        registro = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows.Count

        If registro <> 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ods
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "Abarrotes"
            TextBox1.Text = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows(0).Item("ID")
            TextBox2.Text = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows(0).Item("Nombre")
            TextBox4.Text = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows(0).Item("Cantidad")
            TextBox3.Text = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows(0).Item("Precio")
            TextBox5.Text = ods.Tables("Abarrotes").Rows(0).Item("Tamaño")

            cadena.Close()

        Else
            MsgBox("No existe el codigo", vbCritical, "Aviso")
            cadena.Close()

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Estoy haciendo una base de datos con Access y Visual Basic, ya esta conectada con la base de datos.
Quiero hacer un buscador con un DataGridView pero al momento de yo ejecutar la accion con un boton me aparece ese error

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error me sale en la columna de Oda.Fill(ods, "Abarrotes")

Ya he intentado descargar algo que me ayude a quitar los 3 puntos que aparecen debajo de la variable *oda* pero siguen ahi.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá sea porque ID es numérico y en el where del  ```select``` lo comparas con un string ```ID='  " & textbox1.text & "'"```. Trata de hacer ```ID=" & textbox1.text```

Comment: Los 3 puntos debajo de oda es porque tiene dos inicial8zaciones una en la definición new .... y otra debajo del if. La primera no debería tener new